# Spring MessageSource seems to ignore property fallbackToSystemLocale

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I have problem configuring Spring MessageSource to ignore my system locale. When I call getMessage with null locale parameter I want my MessageSource to choose default property file messages.properties. Instead it chooses messages_en.properties. When I change the name of this property file to messages_fr.properties then default property file is choosen. My system locale is 'en'. So it seems like MessageSource ignores the fallbackToSystemLocale property which I set to false.

This behavior is same with Spring version 4.1.4 as well as 4.1.5.

MessageSource configuration:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"></property>
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>locale/messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
</bean>
```

Getting message:

```
String message = messageSource.getMessage("user.email.notFound", new Object[] {email}, null);
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fallbackToSystemLocale` is **NOT** intended to steer what the message source does when you invoke them with `locale=null`

`fallbackToSystemLocale` control what to do when you request a message (code) that does not exist for the requested local - either because there is no message properties file for the language at all, or just because the message file does not contain the message code

On the other hand when you invoke `getMessage` with  `locale=null` (`messageSource.getMessage("key", null);`) then locale will be set by `Locale.getDefault`

*org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource:*

```
protected String getMessageInternal(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale) {
    ...
    if (locale == null) {
        locale = Locale.getDefault();
    }
    ...
```

BEFORE the `fallbackToSystemLocale` property is taken in account.

Therfore the easyest **hack**-arround (It is not a workarround it is a hack), would be using a language that you not support instead of `null`: 
`messageSource.getMessage("key", new Locale("XX"));`

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. Anyway don't you find this behaviour illogical? I would expect using default message property file in case that null locale is provided. If I wanted to use system local I would do something like `messageSource.getMessage("key", locale==null ? Locale.getDefault() : locale);` . i.e. Wicket framework solve this issue as I write and it seems better to me.
I will probably extend the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` class and override `getMessageInternal` to reflect my needs. If it is not declared as final of course :)